# If I change my computer name how does it affect my computer's paths?

Tags: terminal, path

I wanted to change my computer's name and did so.  I used it for a while but when doing other programming related work felt like I was hitting a wall sometimes because of pathing.

I changed terminal name by executing a command line command and did the rest through **Users** in **System Settings** inside of **Advanced Settings** that you can access by pressing *control* and *clicking* on the User.

Ex. starting up a MySQL server/accessing MySQL command line tools/Python or php acting up.

Can changing my computer's name result in this kind of affect?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean- you can't change the computer name in the Users & Groups pref pane, you do that in the Sharing pref pane. Did you change you user account name accidentally?

In general- changing the Computer Name in Sharing will set the bonjour name (My-Computer.local), you can use the 'scutil' command to set your hostname:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName mycomputer
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying.  I changed the account name.  But then changed it back. @macman